# Reputation for non-Sha'atnez?

Tags: clothing, shaatnez

There are some clothiers that mass-produce their garments.  I wonder if there is

a) a list of companies that don't use Sha'atnez

b) a list of mass-produced garments (such as "Classic Blazer" by Joe Schmoe) that are never made with Sha'atnez due to the designer/manufacturer's specifications for that garment, or

c) any Halachic principle (Hazakah, Rov, etc.) that can be relied upon if there is no such *official* list as above (ie., nobody checks manufacturers, either by phone/written inquiry or by visiting, but enough garments have been checked and are known to Sha'atnez checkers not to have Sha'atnez in them).

Answer (score 4):

According to AFTA Shatnez Testing Center in Chicago, one cannot rely on Hazakah or Rov or anything like that. They say that

- ALL men's, women's, and children's clothing that list wool or linen should be tested.
- ALL jackets and coats should be tested even if wool or linen is not listed
- If contents list "Other Fiber" or "O.F." beware and have the garment tested.

Source: http://www.youngisraelwrp.com/ShatnezPoster7-11.pdf

(The source also lists a bunch of companies that usually/almost always *do* use shatnez.

Comment: How do they know certain companies usually use Shaatnez if not for rov/chazaka?

Comment: @DoubleAA They know based on the idea of rov (or 99.9%) that certain companies usually use shatnez. My point (and AFTA's point) is that one cannot rely on rov to say that a certain garment doesn't have shatnez and therefore wouldn't need to be checked. That's what I understand point c in the question to be asking about.

Comment: How come we can only use rov one way?

Comment: @DoubleAA They're not using Rov in either way. They use it to say that a garment probably has shatnez in the same way that you could theoretically say that it probably doesn't have shatnez. You still have to get it tested, though, if you want to wear it. But if I see that a company's suit is >99% likely to have shatnez, I'll probably just buy a different suit.

Comment: @DoubleAA Even if a majority of a certain manufacturer's products were not shaatnez, is it reasonable to take a chance when there is a possibility to make sure by testing?

Comment: @avrohom yes. We do that all the time with most types of treifa which we don't check for because of rov. (Assuming rov applies here. I'm just saying there is nothing bedieved about using rov)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok perhaps not a majority, but suppose a company makes a particular suit. Every year, they manufacture thousands of that suit. Over time, thousands of that suit have been tested and found not to contain shatnez. As long as they don't change the composition of the suit, one might think that it is not necessary to get a new one tested since we know empirically that the materials used are fine. Of course, that's not what we do, but it is a reasonable thought.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm guessing they don't apply rov because of חזקה שאפשר לברר (I don't know why that doesn't apply to treifos. Never learned it)

Comment: @Daniel Not only is that a reasonable thought, but I've  heard from a *sha'atneiz* checker (contrary to the information in your answer) that certain types of wool suits (with certain characteristics) from certain manufacturers are reliably known to never have *sha'atneiz* and therefore do not halachically need to be checked. They also mentioned that most types of wool suits (that don't mention linen) in the modest to moderate price range are unlikely to have linen in the lining or elsewhere.

Comment: Daniel, the link in your answer is dead.

Answer (score 2):

I just got some suits at Jos. A. Bank. When doing so my first question was, "This may sound like a strange question, but have you ever heard of something called shatnez?" He responded, "Actually, yes, and all of our suits must be tested and aproved as shatnez free before we sell them. Not a stange question, but not one I hear often, though."

Based on comments below and websites I have now seen which state that Joseh a Banks has often tested positive for shatnez I can no longer recommend them as a place to go and was mistaken for having believed them in the first place

Comment: For what it's worth, I see numerous websites that claim Jos. A. Bank is particularly bad with regard to Sha'atnez.

Comment: thanks, recently looked up as well after seeing your comment. won't be wearing my suits until I can get them checked now

Comment: So did your suit have shaatnez or not? Maybe they have newer lines that are free of it or something like that.

Comment: you could be entirely correct but at this point with the information being presented to me I can't rely on just their word and will have to get them checked

Comment: Going back to the old klalim of ne'emanus...

Comment: There are places that check for shatnez but do not attach the certification as "shatnex free" to the suit. Others will send the suit to a shatnez checker **upon request**. You need to ask for the certification when you get the suit. I staple the lable (from the shatnex lab) into my suit jacket in order to be sure that it has been checked.